# A bounded finite intersection of half-spaces is a polyhedron?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry, affine-geometry, polyhedra, convex-hulls

A polyhedron is a convex hull of finitely many points. I would like to show that the intersection of finitely many half spaces is a polyhedron, provided the boundedness.

Is this statement true, in general? If so, can somebody give me a hint to approach it?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Yes, it’s true. No idea how to prove it.

Comment: @bubba You may be please to hear that even Rockafellar considers this non trivial :-).

Comment: @copper.hat. Thanks. I do feel better. I used to have Rockefeller’s book when I was in grad school half a century ago. I wonder what happened to it. I never get rid of books intentionally. Especially since building bookshelves is so much fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite an answer, but a reference.

A classic reference on this is Rockafellar's "Convex Analysis".

Theorem 19.1, The following properties of a convex set $C$ are equivalent:
(a) $C$ is polyhedral.
(b) $C$ is closed and has only finitely many faces.
(c) $C$ is finitely generated.

Note that Rockafellar uses polyhedral to mean the intersection of a finite collection of closed half spaces.

(b) is irrelevant to this question.

Finitely generated means the convex hull of a finite set of points and directions, that is, $C$ is finitely generated **iff** there are $a_1,...,a_m$ and some fixed $k \in \{0,...,m\}$ such that any point of $C$ can be written as
$\sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_i a_i$ with $\lambda_i \ge 0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i = 1$. (This is verbatim from the text, the case $k=0$ requires comment, but is not relevant here as $k=m$ in your question.)

Since you are presuming boundedness, this means there are no directions, and hence finitely generated reduces to the convex hull of a finite number of points.

I liked Rockafellar's comment that precedes Theorem 19.1 so much that I added it to my profile years ago:

> "This classical result is an outstanding example of a fact which is
> completely obvious to geometric intuition, but which wields important
> algebraic content and is not trivial to prove."

Comment: Thank you very much for the information. I not not familiar with the concept of "directions" in this context. Would you be able to add few more words to clarify it.

Comment: A direction $d$ is a non zero vector. We say that a set $C$ recedes in the direction $d$ **iff** $x+\lambda d \in C$ for all $x \in C, \lambda \ge 0$. (Rockafellar's actual definition of a direction is a little different, but the above is sufficient. In your case, the set is bounded by assumption so there are no directions, that is $k=m$.)